# PayPal full refund not working

Tags: paypal

I am trying to initiate a full refund with the PayPal API:

```
$header = Array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
);

$ch = curl_init($aurl . "/v1/payments/sale/{$params['transid']}/refund");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$res = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

I get a status code 400 back and this message:

```
["name"]=> string(19) "TRANSACTION_REFUSED"
["message"]=> string(23) "Request was refused.{0}" 
["information_link"]=> string(76) "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#TRANSACTION_REFUSED" ["debug_id"]=> string(13) "e1df77fc1910c"
```

Partial refunds are working with this code:

```
$header = Array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
);

$ch = curl_init($aurl . "/v1/payments/sale/{$params['transid']}/refund");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(Array("amount" => Array("total" => $_POST['amount'], "currency" => $params['currency']))));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$res = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

[PayPal says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/refund-payment/), full refunds are possible with an empty JSON payload, but this do not work. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done a partial refund for this transaction. When you do try to do a full refund again for the same transaction the transaction will be refused.

`Can not do a full refund after a partial refund`

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution!